# cake php, how to populate a drop down selection based on another drop down selection?

Tags: php, cakephp, drop-down-menu, cakephp-1.3

I have a table something like this:

```
id  test   attr  dim
1   test1  a1    d1
2   test2  a2    d2
3   test3  a1    d3
4   test3  a1    d2
```

I am creating a drop down field that shows the `attr` as having only two options `a1 and a2`. Based on a selection of either `a1` or `a2` i would like to do is something like:

```
if (a1 is selected){$a == a1} else {$a == a2}
$test = mysql_query("SELECT dim FROM xxx WHERE attr = $a")
```

and fill up the second drop down with the results from that query that could be `d1`, `d2` or `d3`

and so on, on multiple drop down lists if I need to.

I know how to do this in regular php but not sure how to do it in CakePHP.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: I'm not sure if i need to use any ajax, this should be working without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with help of `ajax->observefield`

eg:

```
$options = array('url' => 'getcounties', 'update' => 'ExampleCountyI
$ajax->observeField('ExampleStateId', $options);
```

**UPDATED**

observeField is not more available in CakePHP js helper [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Calderoy/2011/01/18/how_to_create_an_observefield_equivalent_in_the_new_jshelper) it's equivalent way to the same for newer `CakePHP version >= 2.x`