# how to create form with a drop-down list that change the other option depend on selection

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I'm trying to create form with a drop-down list that can dynamically show different option when you select an element from the drop-down list.

for example, if you have a drop-down list for the countries and another drop-down for states, when the user selects US from the countries drop-down, the states drop-down should change to show US states. if the user selected Canada , it should show Canadian states in states drop-down.

I hope it's clear and sorry for my complicated explanation.

I need a specific solution for cakePHP and the other thread dosen't answer and solve for the newer version of CakePHP.

Comment: more like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599971/cake-php-how-to-populate-a-drop-down-selection-based-on-another-drop-down-selec?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to find a specific solution for cakePHP but I got bullied instead of getting a good answer. 
After a lot of searching I've found this great blog post which exactly solve my problem.
http://blog.jandorsman.com/2011/01/using-ajax-and-cakephp-to-dynamically-populate-select-form-fields/

If you're using a newer version of CakePHP. you need to use different functions JS helper instead

```
    $this->Js->get('#BookId')->event(
    'change',
    $this->Js->request(
        array('controller'=>'Books','action'=>'your_ajax_function'),
        array('update' => '#BooksAuthorId', 'dataExpression' => true, 'data' => '$("#BookId").serialize()')
    )
);
```

The above code won't generate the javaScript code. It will just cache it. you need to execute this function at the end of your view file to generate the code.

```
<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the arrays from Cake to Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
var pdcs = new Array();


<?php foreach($districts as $d_id => $d_name):
    echo 'pdcs['.$d_id.'] = new Array();';
    echo 'pdcs['.$d_id.'][0] = new Array(';
    if(!empty($project_duty[$d_id])):
        $last_key = end(array_keys($project_duty[$d_id]));
        foreach($project_duty[$d_id] as $code_id => $code):
            if($code_id != $last_key)
            {
                echo '\''.$code.'\',';
            } else {
                if(empty($project_duty['all']))
                {
                    echo '\''.$code.'\'';
                } else {
                    echo '\''.$code.'\',';
                }
            }
        endforeach;
    endif;
    echo ');';

    echo 'pdcs['.$d_id.'][1] = new Array(';
    if(!empty($project_duty[$d_id])):
        foreach($project_duty[$d_id] as $code_id => $code):
            if($code_id != $last_key)
            {
                echo '\''.$code_id.'\',';
            } else {
                if(empty($project_duty['all']))
                {
                    echo '\''.$code_id.'\'';
                } else {
                    echo '\''.$code_id.'\',';
                }
            }
        endforeach;
    endif;
    echo ');';
endforeach;?>
</script>
```

Create some functions to actually change the data in the drop down.  Here the final function changeList will empty the box, select one of the arrays we made earlier, and then it will fill it back up.

```
<script language="javascript">

// This function goes through the options for the given
// drop down box and removes them in preparation for
// a new set of values

function emptyList( box ) {
    // Set each option to null thus removing it
    while ( box.options.length ) box.options[0] = null;
}

// This function assigns new drop down options to the given
// drop down box from the list of lists specified

function fillList( box, arr ) {
    // arr[0] holds the display text
    // arr[1] are the values

    for ( i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++ ) {

        // Create a new drop down option with the
        // display text and value from arr

        option = new Option( arr[0][i], arr[1][i] );

        // Add to the end of the existing options

        box.options[box.length] = option;
    }

    // Preselect option 0

    box.selectedIndex=0;
}

// This function performs a drop down list option change by first
// emptying the existing option list and then assigning a new set

function changeList() {
    // Isolate the appropriate list by using the value
    // of the currently selected option
    box = document.getElementById('TrooperActivityDistrictWorked');
    var boxValue = box.options[box.selectedIndex].value;
    //list = lists[box.options[box.selectedIndex].value];
    pdc = pdcs[boxValue];
    // Next empty the slave list
    slave = document.getElementById('TrooperActivityProjectDuty');
    emptyList( slave );

    // Then assign the new list values

    fillList( slave, pdc );
}
</script>
```

The drop down that calls the javascript functions:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('district_worked', array('label' => '','options' => $districts,'title' => 'Select district daily was worked in', 'empty' => 'Please Choose a Type', 'onchange' => 'changeList()')); ?>
```

The drop down that gets changed based on what was selected:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('project_duty', array('label' => '','options' => '', 'empty' => '(choose one)')); ?>
```

This is just a recent example, let me know if I can expand on this at all.

Comment: I found the method in here http://blog.jandorsman.com/2011/01/using-ajax-and-cakephp-to-dynamically-populate-select-form-fields/ is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Javascript to change the contents of the second select, once the first select has been changed.

A simple example using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("select#selectOne").change(function(){
       // Load options into select two depending on value of select 1
       var currentValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
       // here you can decide what to load, you could use Ajax etc
       $('select#selectTwo').empty().append($("<option>something</option>");
    });
})
```

Comment: I'm using CakePHP framework so I expect there is straightforward solution than this.

Comment: Nope. You will still need to use a frontend technology such as javascript to dynamically update the second select box. A server side technology like PHP Can't do this it's impossible.

once PHP/Server renders the content and sends it to the browser it has no control to change things..

Comment: Well, CakePHP should auto-generate the client side code. I think this is very obvious task and should be implemented in the framework.

Comment: really? :/ So you expect CakePHP.makeMeAniceWebApp(); functionality too I suppose :D

Comment: The .net framework has this and can be implemented automatically. I think the framework should deal with this kind of tasks but I don't expect it to automatically generate a website.

Comment: CackePHP is a PHP Framework, it has nothing to do with frontend development, and nor should it. It's not supposed to do everything for you..